# changes are not being reflected in when getting the result after insert thru hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring

I am using hibernate and spring mvc, when i insert a record in DB, and try to access that that right after that, then i don't get the result. 
e.g. 
if insert a record for newly reg. user and login in him right after registering it then result set is empty. 
I am using hibernate templates.

what could be the problem and what i am missing...

thx.

my [app].servlet.xml

```
      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbb" />
    <property name="username" value="r123" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="hbSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>UserAttributes.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>BlessUser.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>SnsType.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>SnsUser.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>SnsAuthenticator.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
  </bean>
```

DAO method

```
public void saveOrUpdate(E transientObject) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(transientObject);
}
```

HBM

```
<id name="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="bless_uid">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<property column="name" length="255" name="Name" not-null="false" type="java.lang.String" />

<property column="email" length="255" name="Email" not-null="false" type="java.lang.String" />

<property column="user_name" length="255" name="UserName" not-null="false"  type="java.lang.String" />

<property column="password" length="255" name="Password" not-null="false" type="java.lang.String" />

<set name="snsUser" lazy="false" cascade="all" table="sns_User">
  <key column="bless_uid" />
  <one-to-many class="com.utilami.model.SnsUser" />
</set>
```

Comment: Can you post example code of how you are inserting the data and how you are retrieving it?

Comment: i have added it... plz check.

Comment: How are you flushing the cache?

Comment: getHibernateTemplate().flush();

i tried this as well... 
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>

Answer (score 0):

This could be a flush issue as others have suggested, or it may be an issue with the database's configuration itself.  Do you have [MySQL configured to auto-commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)?  It may also be that you have a long-lasting transaction (Hibernate has not yet completed the transaction, so the commit is delayed).